# The best way to check if List<String[]> contains a String[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, collections

I have a `List` declared as:

```
List<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This `List` contains multiple arrays of `String`s.

I need to check if a `String[]` which I have is contained in this `ArrayList<String[]>`.

I am currently iterating through the `ArrayList` and comparing each `String[]` with the one I am searching for:

```
for(String[] array: arrayList){
    if(Arrays.equals(array, myStringArray)){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Is there any better way to check if an `ArrayList<String[]>` contains a specific `String[]`?

Comment: Seems fine. What's wrong with current approach ?

Comment: `arrayList.contains(myStringArray)`

Comment: @Suresh there is nothing wrong. Im looking if this can be achieved in a more efficient way..?

Comment: @bigdestroyer This does not work.

Comment: I agree with @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - your efficiency can't be better than`O(n*n)` (equals takes `n` BTW)

Comment: What is meant with "the best way": best performing, shortest expression, something else?

Comment: @heikkim By best I meant the performance.

Comment: `if(!Arrays.equals())` Did you really want to **negate** equals?

Comment: "I need to check if [...] is present" - This is exactly why God gave us hash sets.

Comment: @icza You are right. We shouldn't negate. This was an extract.

Comment: @Swad are you constructing the list?

Comment: If you are creating the `List` then checking `contains` **many times without modifying the contents** then you should transfer your `String[]` into `List<String>` and then transfer your `List<String[]>` into a `Set<List<String>>`. This will allow the `Set` to provide you with `O(1)` contains. This assumes that the `String[]` are unqiue within the `List`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider /agree ! Mixing [] with generics, especially [] with lists is a *bad* idea roughly 95% of the time (see Bloch EJ 2nd for rationale and examples) - either stay with [][] (which is a lot easier to use in Java than in C) or List<List<>>/Set<List<>> ; I consider the problem deeper than what OP thinks it is - his problems come not from (arguable) lack of API knowledge, but from using the wrong abstraction.

Comment: Can't you use a Set? It will be much more efficient in most cases, when you just Store all your Arrays in a HashSet and use contains() - all the logic is already inside, and collisions are handled gracefully :-)

Comment: @Falco this will not work - an array does not override `hashCode` and `equals` so `contains` will not work. You need to use a collection that overrides these methods correctly - anything from the collections framework would work. This is why I suggest a `Set<List>>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Array.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[])) is the most efficient method *afaik*. That method alone meant for the purpose and optimized as less as it is in the [current state](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.equals%28char%5B%5D%2Cchar%5B%5D%29) of implementation which is a single `for` loop.

Just go for it.

Comment: in my opinion this is not a response, it doesn't add any value to the current post. It would've been enough if you would've added it as comment to the question...

Comment: @user503413 -1 ?? When OP asked for the best way, I'm just telling that the current way is the best way. It just like  a yes/or question.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the answer from Rod_Algonquin, but there is another way to do it. Just write your own class wrapping your array and implement a custom equals and hashCode method and let them return Arrays.equals() and Arrays.hashCode(). With this approach you can store your objects in a List and do contains checks on the list directly.

```
List<ArrayWrapper> list = new ArrayList<ArrayWrapper>();
list.add(new ArrayWrapper(new String[]{"test", "123"}));
list.add(new ArrayWrapper(new String[]{"abc", "def"}));
list.add(new ArrayWrapper(new String[]{"789", "cgf"}));

String[] arrayToSearchFor = {"test", "123"};
ArrayWrapper wrapperToSearchFor = new ArrayWrapper(arrayToSearchFor);
System.out.println(list.contains(wrapperToSearchFor));

String[] arrayToSearchFor2 = {"hello", "123"};
ArrayWrapper wrapperToSearchFor2 = new ArrayWrapper(arrayToSearchFor2);
System.out.println(list.contains(wrapperToSearchFor2));


class ArrayWrapper
{
    private String[] array;

    public ArrayWrapper(String[] array)
    {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public String[] getArray()
    {
        return array;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return Arrays.hashCode(array);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj instanceof ArrayWrapper))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Arrays.equals(array, ((ArrayWrapper) obj).getArray());
    }
}
```

this will print

```
true
false
```

Comment: Great idea, but wouldn't it be even better if you used a `Set` instead of a `List` and let `ArrayWrapper` cache its `hashCode`?

Comment: @Yogu depends on OP's needs. He said he has a list, so maybe he needs to get elements by index. Caching the hashcode will only work if the arrays are never modified.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably look for a solution where you don't store `String[]` objects directly in your list. That'd probably mean creating some kind of meaningful class that might store a `String[]` internally, or it might mean just switching to ArrayLists instead of arrays. Without knowing the context, though, the best I can suggest is wrapping them with lists using [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)

```
// Make a List that uses the provided array for its contents:
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(stringArray);
```

This gives you useful `hashCode` and `equals` methods, which allows you to use `ArrayList.contains`, or even `HashSet`s if containment testing is the primary concern:

```
Set<List<String>> stringLists = new HashSet<>();

// when you want to add a String[]:
stringLists.add(Arrays.asList(stringArray));

// when you want to check whether a String[] is in the set:
stringLists.contains(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
```

`ArrayList.contains` won't be any faster than what you're currently doing, and all the `Arrays.asList` calls are likely to be quite wordy, but `HashSet.contains` has the potential to be much faster than what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

[`List.contains(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) is broken with lists of arrays, so why don't you use lists of lists?

You can easily convert an array into a list with [`Arrays.asList(T... a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).

```
String[] array = new String[2];
array[0] = "item1";
array[1] = "item2";
List<List<String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
arrayList.add(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: it is true because you pass the same reference to the String array that was added. try making a new array with the same content of `array `

Comment: Yes, and passing another instance of the array with the same elements will return `false` (but should also return `true`)!

Comment: Improved with a suggestion.